# How can I get the name of each user by his id?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.rootid AS user_id, p1.rid AS friend_id
 FROM relations p1
WHERE rootid = 1246
   OR rootid IN (SELECT p2.rid
              FROM relations p2
              WHERE rootid = 1246);
```

The result of it is something like this:

[image]

Also I have a table which contains names. Something like this:

```
// users
+------+_--------+
|  id  |  name   |
+------+---------+
| 1246 | Jack    |
| 1247 | Peter   |
| 1246 | Ali     |
| .    | .       |
| .    | .       |
| .    | .       |
+------+---------+
```

Now I want to get **names** instead of **ids**  in the output. Noted that both `user_id` and `friend_id` refer to `users` table. How can I do that?

Comment: You means, you want to get user_name instead of user_id and friend_name instead of friend_id right ?

Comment: Use join with user table

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
SELECT u1.name user_name, u2.name friend_name from relations r
INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.id = r.user_id
INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = r.friend_id
where r.user_id = 1246
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT  u.name AS user_name, f.name AS friend_name
 FROM relations p1
 INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = p1.rootid
 INNER JOIN user f ON f.id = p1.rid
WHERE rootid = 1246
   OR rootid IN (SELECT p2.rid
              FROM relations p2
              WHERE rootid = 1246);
```